# Complex ORDER BY Statement

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, firebird

I have this query:

```
SELECT itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName,
       count(tagID) as qtTag,
       count(modalityID) as qt_Modality, extra
       FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID
       WHERE (collectionID = :collectionID) AND (tagID = :tagID1 OR tagID = :tagID2) group by itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName, extra ORDER BY EXTRA;
```

Now, every ITEM is connected to one or many TAGID's. What I need is to order the result in a way that ITEMS linked to TagID1 and TagID2 comes first in order the others could be ordered by EXTRA field. 
Is it possible to do that?
I have tried with  ORDER BY CASE statement but I cannot make it work it out.

this is a sample of the result:

[image]

As you can see, the items are ordered by the EXTRA field. But I need to put ITEMS linked to TagID1 and TagID2 first, but these fields are not shown in the result. All I need is the order.

I had tried this code, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName,
       count(tagID) as qtTag,
       count(modalityID) as qt_Modality, extra
       FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID
       WHERE (collectionID = :collectionID) AND (tagID = :tagID1 OR tagID = :tagID2) group by itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName, extra ORDER BY CASE WHEN tagID1 = :TagID1 THEN 1 WHEN tagID2 = :tagID2 THEN 2 END,  EXTRA;
```

Obs. I'm using Firebird 3.0 database

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: The code you tried and the result obtained would also help.

Comment: Do you really mean to `GROUP BY` all of those columns? Based on the small amount of data that you've provided, it seems like way too much granularity to get any kind of meaning from aggregate functions.

Comment: Note that ALL of the items in the result will be linked to tagID1 or tagID2 because of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
SELECT itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName,
       count(tagID) as qtTag,
       count(modalityID) as qt_Modality, 
       extra
       FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID
       WHERE (collectionID = :collectionID) AND (tagID = :tagID1 OR tagID = :tagID2) 
       group by itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName, extra, tagID
       ORDER BY        
       (CASE
       WHEN tagID = 'tagID1' THEN 1
       WHEN tagID = 'tagID2' THEN 2
       ELSE 3
       END), extra
```

Comment: Hi @Rainman I received this message: Invalid expression in the ORDER BY clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

Comment: Answer has been updated. Notice that TagID wasn't grouped. I added it.

Comment: Perfect @Rainman just one more thing is it possible to show first the items linked to both tagID1 AND tagID2? Now the result is showing all items tagID1 then all tagID2, but there are some items linked to both. I need to give priority to them. ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mean that tagID might be "TagID1TagID2" for some rows ?

Comment: Yes @Rainman, some rows are linked both to TagID1 and TagID2. Do you think that is it possible to do it with one Select only?